# Sub-directory of subsite 1 accesses subsite 2 as URL rewrite -- Wordpress Mult-site

Tags: wordpress, apache2, multisite

Use Case:

1. Sub-Site A resides at domain https://subsiteA.com
2. Sub-Site B resides at domain https://subsiteB.com

Both of these subsites belong to the same Wordpress Multi-site Network and **are on the same server.**

Would it be possible to route a URL such as https://subsiteA.com/subSiteB
and display Sub-site B without changing the URL... I've looked into MU domain mapping plugin, this plugin as well: https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator and apache2 reverse proxy to no avail.

*TLDR* Map sub-directory of sub-site A to sub-site B of which are on the same WP-network without a browser redirect.

I can provide the production URL's in a message if needed. Thank you.

Comment: If site A and site B are on the same server this is possible.  Apache reverse proxy does support this.  https://serverfault.com/questions/918033/redirect-web-page-to-another-site-without-changing-url

Comment: Hello ended up using apache2 reverse proxy:

Answer (score 0):

Reverse proxy via apache2 did the trick:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /subsiteB https://subsiteB.com
ProxyPassReverse /subsiteB https://subsiteB.com
```

Put this inside of your virtual host where your "/subsiteB" website is located.